# How to do a auto submit for the "Search" function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, model-view-controller, entity

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p id="a">
        Search par VCMEMBRE/VCPARENT: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
        <input type="submit" name="searchType" value="Find!" />
    </p>
}
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        axeModel.trcubezonequotas = db.TRCUBEZONEQUOTAS.Where(
            (s =>
                   s.VCMEMBRE.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
                || s.VCPARENT.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
            )
        );
        return View(axeModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

in your html tag assign a function for onChange event.

```
<input type="text" id="search" onchange="myFunction()"  name="searchType" value="Find!" />
```

then write the function to call your controller method :)

for example :

```
function myFunction(){
var searchterm = $("#search");
$.get( "your controller url", { searchString: searchterm} )
  .done(function( searchResults) {
    searchResults.each(function( index ) {
       console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
    });   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning

I thank you enormously for your help

I have modified the code like this :

**My View:**

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
         <p id="a">
        <input type="text" id="search" onchange="myFunction()"  name="searchType" value="Find!" /> 
          </p>
        }

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    function myFunction(){
    var searchterm = $("#search");
    $.get( "Index","SaisieReferentiel", { searchString: searchterm} )
      .done(function( searchResults) {
        searchResults.each(function( index ) {
           console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
        });   
      });
    }
    </script>
```

**My Controller:**

```
  public class SaisieReferentielController : Controller
    {
    public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            axeModel.trcubezonequotas = db.TRCUBEZONEQUOTAS.Where(
                (s =>
                       s.VCMEMBRE.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
                    || s.VCPARENT.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
                )
            );
            return View(axeModel);
        }
}
```

But I have a mistake in my JavaScript :
**JavaScript runtime error: Object does not support the property or method "each"**